# fish + script -> chaos, what options?

Tags: fish

The fish shell uses many escape sequences as you type, especially if you ever make a mistake or use completion.

'script' just captures them literally, making quite a mess. More of a mess than `col -b` can repair.

Is there some other way to record command lines and their results (other than just using an emacs shell buffer, which I might resort to)?

Is there a way to configure fish to, ahem, scale back it's fancy display?

Comment: No, and that is not specific to `fish` or some other shell `bash`; indeed *emacs* shell buffer is a good alternative. You could configure your shell's history.

Comment: I know it's not fish-specific, but I wondered if fish in particular had some configuration.

Comment: To kill ANSI junk: `sed 's/[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\(;[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\?\)\?[mK]//g' -- file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll lose many of the nice features of fish - colourisation, autosuggestions, etc., but you can start `script` with the environment variable `TERM` set to `dumb`. This will result in a much cleaner output. `script` really is a dumb terminal - the manpage suggests that it is supposed to emulate an old-style hardcopy terminal!

```
env TERM=dumb script
```